# Why did Delilah try to kill Daud?

Tags: dishonored

In the first Dishonored add-on, the witch Delilah

> helps Billie Lurk to usurp Daud as leader of the Whalers

Daud is warned by the Outsider and goes after her, defeating her in the second add-on, but not before it is revealed that

> her ultimate goal was to enter Emily's body to become Empress.

So, why was Delilah plotting against Daud anyway? It seems completely unnecessary and in the end only ruined her plans...

Comment: I know the game's been out for years but I am impressed you managed to spoil the endings of both DLCs in a single sentence.

Comment: I do agree it can ruin the fun for some people. I edited the question and wrapped everything into a spoiler block

Comment: **Suggested edits that just add spoiler tags should not be approved.**  If you're hiding the whole question, you're just making it harder for people to answer it.  If you yourself don't want to be spoiled, I suggest you don't look at the question.

Comment: If the question title doesn't tip you off that there will be spoilers, I can't help you. I appreciate that @CaffeinatedCake tried to fix it though, instead of merely complaining about it.

Comment: Its more than likely that this is a plot hole and thus I doubt you will get an answer for this.

Answer (score 4):

A better question might be, *why did Daud try to kill Delilah?* The answer, of course, is that the Outsider set him on the path towards Delilah, after which Daud's guilt led him towards protecting Emily.

Recall that the Outsider also appears to Delilah, presumably with some regularity, and we can guess that the Outsider has mentioned Daud's name to her. The Outsider does seem to enjoy helping along this sort of chaos so he can watch the story unfold.

Of course, it's also possible that, since Daud has been loudly running around Dunwall asking everyone in sight about a woman named Delilah, word got back to her and she just assumed that if a legendary assassin is looking for you, it can't be good. Killing Daud would then just be a smart precaution on her way to ruling the empire. (Even if you assume that word of Daud doesn't get out, Delilah could hardly fail to notice that anyone with any connection to her is disappearing.)

Or it may even be pettier than that. From *Rumors and Sightings: Daud* (found on Corvo's desk in the base game):

> The earliest stories tell of a gang-killer without mercy, moving among the shop keepers and City Watch officers of Dunwall like a reaper through wheat. ... Daud is even purported to have spent a winter in the Academy of Natural Philosophy itself. **And for a time, before a schism developed, he counted the Brigmore Witches among his allies.** All the while, he honed his craft, and it is during this time that we believe he began to consort with the Outsider.

Unfortunately the game is not explicit on this point, so there is no canon answer. I assume that it is very much about self-defense, as there's no indication that she's going after Corvo, who is also touched by the Outsider; but there are valid alternate theories as well.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because by Daud delivering Emily to Burrows' agents after the assassination of the Empress, made it more difficult for Delilah to enter Emily's body.
OR
Delilah possibly became obsessed with Daud as he had powers given to him by the Outsider and Delilah may have wanted these powers.

Source: http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Daud

Hope this helps to wrap up your question.

P.S. I am NO expert on Dishonored lore, so there may be loopholes in these theories. :)